# Prove that the set of real symmetric matrices is closed

Tags: general-topology, matrices

The scalar product defined for the matrices $A$ and $B$ in $R^{n\times n}$ is

$$ \langle A, B \rangle = trace(A^{T} B) $$.

I want to show that the set of all symmetric matrices ($D$) is closed in $R^{n\times n}$.

My attempt:

I want to show that $\overline{D} \subset D $. Let $A \in \overline{D}$. Then there exists a sequence $A_n \in D$ such that $||A-A_{n}|| \to 0$.

$$||A-A_n||^2 = trace((A-A_n)^{T}(A-A_n) $$

Expanding this and using linearity of trace operator, I get,

$$||A-A_n||^2= trace(A^{T} A)-trace(A^{T}A_n)-trace(A_n^T A)+trace(A_n^T A_n) $$
So, I get that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}(||A||^2-2\langle A, A_n \rangle + ||A_n||^2)=0$$

I am not able to show that $A$ is symmetric, from here. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decomposing into symmetric and antisymmetric parts we have $A= \frac12 (A+A^T)+\frac12 (A-A^T)$. We also know that $A_n = \frac12 (A_n + A_n^T)$ since it was assumed symmetric. Now if $A \neq A^T$ then $A-A^T \neq 0$ so $\|A -A^T\|\neq 0$ however $$\|A-A_n\|=\|\frac12(A-A_n+A^T-A_n^T) +\frac12 (A-A^T)\|$$ and taking the limit with $n \to \infty$ gives $$\|A-A_n\|=\frac12\|(A-A^T)\| \neq 0$$ which contradicts that $A_n \to A$. This implies $A-A^T=0$ and so $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Alternatively, note that the function $f: A \mapsto A - A^T$ is continuous and that the set of symmetric matrices is $f^{-1}(0)$, which is closed because $\{0\}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: On taking the limit with $n \to \infty$, we get the last expression because $||.||$ is continuous right? So, the Frobenius norm isn't special here?

Comment: @wolf_pack_32 Yes it relies on the continuity of the norm. As you noticed, the Frobenius norm isn't special as long as the metric is induced by the norm.